# In Groovy - How to Iterate the versions in the list?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am performing below task in jenkinsfile using groovy. where i have below variables

```
list C=[1.1,1.2,1.3]

String A=1.1
String B=1.3
```

```
if ("${A}" == "${B}") {
      echo "No Action needed"
} else if ("${A}" != "${B}") {

   then check in the variable list C and then iterate the list in sequential order. 
     
 }
```

Need Help in this condition. I am newbie in groovy.
When the **A** is != to **B** then it check the version from list **C**

**Expected Output:-**

```
1.1 == 1.3

then check in list C [1.1,1.2,1.3]

Iterate
1.2 ==1.3
print "still need iteration"

1.3 == 1.3
print " Matched"
```

I have Tried below code but its not doing iteration in for loop for If condition.

```
def C = ['1.1', '1.2', '1.3']
A=1.1
B=1.3

   if ('${A}' == '${B}') {
       println "equal"
   }
   
    else if ('${A}' != '${B}') {
       println "not equal"
       
       for (i = 0; i < C.size(); i++) {
           println  C[i]
      
           if ('C[i]' == '${B}') {
          println "equal"
   }
       }     
  
}
```

Comment: "then check in the variable list C and then iterate the list in sequential order" - What do you want to happen during iteration?

Comment: I have to perform deployments of that versions.

Answer (score 0):

there are several issues in your code

1. `A`,`B` are numeric and `C` is array of strings. to compare objects you need same type.
2. `'C[i]' == '${B}'` is incorrect because you are comparing literal string `'C[i]'` to B converted to GString `"1.3"`
3. better to avoid this kind of comparison `'${A}' == '${B}'` - result could be tricky. better to use `A == B`

so, your code with changes

```
def C = ['1.1', '1.2', '1.3']
A='1.1'
B='1.3'

if (A == B) {
   println "equal"
} else {
   println "not equal"
   for (i = 0; i < C.size(); i++) {
       println  C[i]
       if (C[i] == B) {
          println "equal"
       }
   }     
}
```

result:

```
not equal
1.1
1.2
1.3
equal
```